# check the returned value is not NULL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I trie to check if the returned value from objectForKey is not NULL

```
if([[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]objectForKey:@"country"])
formViewController.country=[[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]objectForKey:@"country"];
```

But i have an error on the first line

**UPDATE**

fbResult is a JSON string,if the user has puted ​​his city and his country in facebook it look like :

```
 "birthday_date" = "07/*****9";
    "contact_email" = "***mehdi@hotmail.fr";
    "current_location" =     {
        city = Tunis;
        country = Tunisia;
        id = 11166369***;
        name = "Tunis, Tunisia";
        state = Qabis;
        zip = "";
    };
    locale = "fr_FR";
    name = "Mehdi ****el";
    pic = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-********_s.jpg";
    sex = male;
    uid = 530****;
}
```

and if the user did not put his country and city it look like :

```
   { "birthday_date" = "02/*3/19**";
        "contact_email" = "kev**kevin@gmail.com";
        "current_location" = "<null>";
        locale = "fr_FR";
        name = "Aude ***";
        pic = "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/4***2_**8_1112_s.jpg";
        sex = female;
        uid = 11***04*;
    }
```

error is

-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96

Comment: What is `fbResult` and what is `[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]`?

Comment: ...and that error would be? Wait, don't tell me. I love to guess.

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of error you get? It could be all kinds of things. Maybe fbResult is not a dictionary, or the result of `[dbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]` could be something you're not expecting.

Comment: There's also an 'error' in your question. You have to guess what it is, it's more fun that way. :)

Comment: post edited. @occulus what is my error ? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking for existence of an object within a dictionary that is nested in another dictionary is not going to catch all occurrences of bad data.

To make your code more solid

```
id current_location = [fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"];
if (current_location != nil && [current_location class] != [NSNull class]) {

    id country = [current_location objectForKey:@"country"];
    if (country != nil) {
        formViewController.country= country;
    } else {
        // current_location has no country
    } 

} else {
    // fbResult has no current_location
}
```

If the current_location is supposed to be a dictionary you can swap out `id currentLocation` with `NSDictionary * currentLocation`

from your update, your current_location can potentially be an instance of `NSNull`

you can check against that with

[yourObject class] != [NSNull class]

Comment: i tried this code but i alwayse have error on id country = [current_location objectForKey:@"country"];
  :( -[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12de5e8
2011-12-10 13:58:11.912 Fpsy[1623:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12de5e8'

Comment: @Mehdi thanks for the update. The code has been updated and should work for you now. I changed the NULL test to actually work... [current_location class] != [NSNull class]